# CSS on hover animation text flip not working?

Tags: html, css, animation, effect

For some reason I can't get this simple css animation using point of origin and pseudoelement to work, the text should flip on its own center.

Take a look at the code:

```css
.flip{
    border: none;
 background-color:none;
 color: black;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 font-size: 18px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 transition: all 500ms ease; 
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

flip:after {
 top: -100%;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 background: none;
 border-radius: 4px;
 content: 'flipped';
 transform-origin: left bottom;
 transform: rotateX(90deg);
}

flip:hover {
 transform-origin: center bottom;
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<a class="flip" href="">flip</a>
```

Comment: `display:inline-block;` on your element and correct the selector

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a "." before your class names in the css

Comment: not only this ... by the way I don't think it's suitable to answer for a typo error